# Trying to add a React snippit but getting error. useRef is not a function

Tags: reactjs, stack-overflow

I'm trying to add a snippet to stackoverflow but I keep getting this error:

> react-dom.production.min.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: useRef is not a function

[image]

I'm doing everything it suggests but I keep getting the error for react dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the scripts to the latest version `16.8.4`.

[Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/7867822) (See last example)

Comment: @me-me Great, be sure to accept if the answer helped :)